Computing correlation coefficient between crime vs non-spatial data (such as no. of population) using ArcMap
I have a polygon divided in neighborhoods (barrios) which contains no. of crime (cases) per barrio. Also, in that polygon, there is a column for the total population of that barrio. Now, I want to compute the correlation coefficient of the crime occurences and the population per barrios.
How can I compute this in ArcMap?

Yes, you absolutely can perform such an analysis with ArcGIS. There are, in fact, many ways. Boolean questions are rarely the right way to get a solution to a problem. Instead of asking about "can I" you need to focus on the "how". Since there are many ways to compute correlation, you would probably get a quicker answer by researching  to ways available, then researching a chosen methodology, and trying  to do the analysis. Then, if you run into difficulty, you'll have sufficient details in the Question to obtain an Answer.
